# C++ WinAPI old-styled window

Tags: c++, winapi, styles, window

I want to create a window like this in C++:

http://winprog.org/tutorial/images/simple_window.gif

The problem is that when I create the window in windows 7, it gets windows 7's styles and I want to make it look old. How can I do it? I searched for this, but all I could find is people who want to make their buttons more modern.

Comment: Why don't you want to respect the user's chosen theme?

Comment: it's just for my own usage because I like them

Comment: But then why not change *your* theme to the classic theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SetWindowTheme` function found in `Uxtheme.h`

1. Add dependency to `uxtheme.lib` in `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`
2. Include `<Uxtheme.h>`
3. Call `SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L" ", L" ");` after you create the window.

An example is below (shell taken from winprog.org sample)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Uxtheme.h>

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        "The title of my window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L" ", L" "); // ADD THIS
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

[image]

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comments:

Picture for including dependency:
[image: dependency]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it's saying SetWindowTheme() is not declared even though I linked the library libuxtheme.a and included the uxtheme.h library, what am I doing wrong? By the way, I'm using Dev-C++

Comment: @user2686435 Did you literally include "libuxtheme.h"? That is not a proper header or library. It should be "uxtheme.lib" as the dependency and "Uxtheme.h" as the header to include.

Comment: Sorry, read the comment again, I edited it. I mean I linked libuxtheme.a and included uxtheme.h

Comment: @user2686435 Edited answer to include a picture for what it's worth.

Comment: @user2686435 Not sure about Dev-C++ and the way it works with dependencies. This is using Visual Studio.

Comment: In Dev-C++, there's a directory called /lib containing libuxtheme.a (and a lot other .a files, whose names all start with "lib").

Comment: @user2686435 The screenshot is Visual Studio Express 2012.

Answer (score -3):

The window UI styling in Windows is global, unless you skin the window yourself, which you would have to do to get your desired effect.

Comment: so how can I skin the window so it looks close or equal to the one I posted an image to?

Comment: That would probably take too long to answer here. Try this for starters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195%28v=vs.85%29.aspx